# ADF Access page binding in View Object's Bind Variables

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a binding on an ADF page, called eventID.  I have a View Object which I'm trying to select from the database based on the value of this eventID.  I have the View Object with a View Criteria, and it uses a "bind variables" defined in the View Object to select based on a value.  I need to make the value of the "bound variable" equal to one of the page's bindings, I think I need to do this based on an expression that resolves to the page's binding "eventID", how do I do this?

I have tried to make the value of the Bind Variable equal to the expression `#{bindings.eventID}` but this throws a Groovy exception when I click on "Test":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases I am not using `declarative` approach. You can execute a method that will  execute the query with the `bind variable`'s value. The following code is a sample `query` for default `HR` schema that comes with `Oracle` database:

```
int empID=123;  // sample employee id

//declares application module and view object
AppModuleImpl appMod = (AppModuleImpl)(JSFUtils.getApplicationModule("AppModuleDataControl"));
ViewObject employeesVO = appMod.findViewObject("EmployeeView");

// start building your query
employeesVO.setWhereClause(null);
employeesVO.setWhereClauseParams(null);
employeesVO.setWhereClause("EMPLOYEE_ID = :1");
employeesVO.setWhereClauseParam(0, empID);
employeesVO.executeQuery();
```

If you still interested in the `declarative` way, checks this link. It may help you:

[enter link description here](http://technology.amis.nl/2011/11/28/synchronize-viewobject-queryies-by-dynamically-linking-bind-parameters/)